# How to get DISABLE primary key flag in oracle jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I create a table and want to judge whether primary key is disabled,

```
rsColumns = meta.getPrimaryKeys(null, owner, tableName);
```

I can not see any info related to this, please give some help, thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE PKEY_TB3 (
INT_C1 INT PRIMARY KEY DISABLE,
VCHAR_C2 VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT COL2_NAME_NN  NOT NULL,
VCHAR_C3 VARCHAR2(30));
```

Comment: You can't do that with the JDBC API, you need to query the Oracle system catalog tables directly.

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2382108?tstart=0     here you can get your solution.